# loading li from external html in search box

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to li in separate html and search box in other html means two html 
    how to load li from external html page to search box working properly.

my working search box code html is like this here li are in the same html search box but i want to divide the code in to two separate html one for search box and other for li load them as external html

```js
  function myFunction() {
        var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
        li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
        for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
            a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
            if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                li[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                li[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
```

```css
  * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    #myInput {
      background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
      background-position: 10px 12px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
    
    #myUL {
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    #myUL li a {
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
      background-color: #f6f6f6;
      padding: 12px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 18px;
      color: black;
      display: block
    }
    
    #myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
      background-color: #eee;
    }
```

```html
 <h2>My Phonebook</h2>
 <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
    
    <ul id="myUL">
      <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: <ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>

Comment: can you use jquery?

Comment: the li should be in a separate html from search box or placeholder because i have large number of li when i load search box it take a time to appear.

Comment: I understand but can you use Jquery?

Comment: So far, all i have understood is, Your search box and list items both are in different pages. My question is, Do you want both search box page and List page to show in a same page.?